# NestJS throw from ExceptionFilter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, exception, nestjs

I try to use an `ExceptionFilter` to map exceptions to their HTTP counterpart.

This is my code :

```
@Catch(EntityNotFoundError)
export class EntityNotFoundFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: EntityNotFoundError, _host: ArgumentsHost) {
        throw new NotFoundException(exception.message);
    }
}
```

But, when the filter code is executed, I got a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

```
 (node:3065) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [object Object]
    at EntityNotFoundFilter.catch ([...]/errors.ts:32:15)
    at ExceptionsHandler.invokeCustomFilters ([...]/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:49:26)
     at ExceptionsHandler.next ([...]/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:13:18)
     at [...]/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:12:35
     at <anonymous>
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
 (node:3065) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`ExceptionFilter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) is always the last place that gets called before a response is sent out, it is responsible for building the response. You cannot rethrow an exception from within an `ExceptionFilter`.

```
@Catch(EntityNotFoundError)
export class EntityNotFoundFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: EntityNotFoundError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
      response.status(404).json({ message: exception.message });
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can create an [`Interceptor`](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) that transforms your errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotFoundInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // next.handle() is an Observable of the controller's result value
    return next.handle()
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof EntityNotFoundError) {
          throw new NotFoundException(error.message);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      }));
  }
}
```

Try it out in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/7zw47o8961?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts).

Comment: Ok. But it seems strange to build manually the body of the response. There is no built-in mechanism to map exception to http responses ? I don't think i try to do something very unusual

Comment: Alternatively, you can use an interceptor, see my edit. Setting the response is not unusual for exception filters however, it's the default. See https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: I've created a live example for you to try it out: https://codesandbox.io/embed/7zw47o8961?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts

Comment: I don't think it's good advice to implement all this ceremony when the NestJS exception classes are already automatically converted to appropriate HTTP responses

Comment: Sure, directly throwing a nest exception (or a subclass) is another (obvious?) option. But if you don't have control over the errors thrown e.g. MongoError, then this seems like a viable solution to me.

Comment: Since the OP wanted to (re)throw a nest option from the beginning, I assumed they were aware of this.

Comment: Jemar is showin how to properly "map" to the NestJS builtin exception: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65473464/6764310

Answer (score 10):

The key here is to extend the `BaseExceptionFilter` and delegate to the super class rather than throwing:

```js
import { BaseExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/core';
// .. your other imports

@Catch(EntityNotFoundError)
export class EntityNotFoundFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: EntityNotFoundError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        super.catch(new NotFoundException(exception.message, host));
    }
}
```

Be sure to pass in the `applicationRef` argument when constructing your filter during your application bootstrapping, because the `BaseExceptionFilter` needs this property to behave correctly

```js
import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';
// .. your other imports

async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  // .. blah blah
  const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new GeneralErrorFilter(httpAdapter));
  // .. blah blah
}
```

This will result in the default error handling you would receive if you had thrown the same error.

Comment: I really like this solution because it uses the NestJS `NotFoundException`. But I would recommend to be careful with forwarding the `exception.message`. Depending on your query you could expose more than you intended to do. In my case I simply opted against any more details.

Comment: It should be `super.catch(new NotFoundException(exception.message), host);`. The `host` is the second parameter for `super.catch()`.

Answer (score 4):

Base on Kim Kern solution I've created this abstract class

```
export abstract class AbstractErrorInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor {
    protected interceptedType: new (...args) => T;

    intercept(
        context: ExecutionContext,
        call$: Observable<any>,
    ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
        return call$.pipe(
            catchError(exception => {
                if (exception instanceof this.interceptedType) {
                    this.handleError(exception);
                }
                throw exception;
            }),
        );
    }

    abstract handleError(exception: T);
}
```

And some implementations

```
export class EntityNotFoundFilter extends AbstractErrorInterceptor<EntityNotFoundError> {
    interceptedType = EntityNotFoundError;

    handleError(exception: EntityNotFoundError) {
        throw new NotFoundException(exception.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that you are creating your own version of the HTTP based exception classes that already ship with NestJS. By default, these will be automatically converted to HTTP responses with the correct error codes. You're adding overhead with Interceptors and abstract class implementations when instead you can just throw NestJS errors and get it for free. This is the built-in mechanism that you were referring to.

`throw new BadRequestException('you done goofed');`

results in:

`{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"you done goofed"}`

[Codesandbox (adapted from Kim's)](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1y6p97v3)

Comment: I don't create my own version of HTTP based exception classes : i want to use them ! But i don't want to explicitely throw http based exception from business code, because that logic can be reused in non-http context (websocket for example). I want to throw business exception (UnderAgeException for example, if i check age of user for some feature), and then, map them to their Http counterpart (BadRequestException in our example).